# Scanner.findAll() and Matcher.results() work differently for same input text and pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner, java-9

I have seen this interesting thing during split of properties string using regex. I am not able to find the root cause.

I have a string which contains text like properties key=value pair.
I have a regex which split the string into keys/values based on the **=** position. It considers first **=** as the split point. Value can also contain = in it.

I tried using two different ways in Java to do it.

1. using **Scanner.findAll()** method

   This is not behaving as expected. It should extract and print all keys based on pattern. But I found its behaving weird. I have one key-value pair as below

```
    SectionError.ErrorMessage=errorlevel=Warning {HelpMessage:This is very important message This is very important .....}
```

The key which should be extracted is **SectionError.ErrorMessage=** but it also considers **errorlevel=** as key.

The interesting point is if I remove one of characters from properties String passed, it behaves fine and only extracts **SectionError.ErrorMessage=** key.

2. using **Matcher.results()** method

   This works fine. No problem whatever we put in the properties string.

Sample code I tried :

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.util.regex.Pattern.MULTILINE;

public class MessageSplitTest {

    static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+=", MULTILINE);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String properties =
                "SectionOne.KeyOne=first value\n" + // removing one char from here would make the scanner method print expected keys
                        "SectionOne.KeyTwo=second value\n" +
                        "SectionTwo.UUIDOne=379d827d-cf54-4a41-a3f7-1ca71568a0fa\n" +
                        "SectionTwo.UUIDTwo=384eef1f-b579-4913-a40c-2ba22c96edf0\n" +
                        "SectionTwo.UUIDThree=c10f1bb7-d984-422f-81ef-254023e32e5c\n" +
                        "SectionTwo.KeyFive=hello-world-sample\n" +
                        "SectionThree.KeyOne=first value\n" +
                        "SectionThree.KeyTwo=second value additional text just to increase the length of the text in this value still not enough adding more strings here n there\n" +
                        "SectionError.ErrorMessage=errorlevel=Warning {HelpMessage:This is very important message This is very important message This is very important messageThis is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important messageThis is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important message This is very important message}\n" +
                        "SectionFour.KeyOne=sixth value\n" +
                        "SectionLast.KeyOne=Country";

        printKeyValuesFromPropertiesUsingScanner(properties);
        System.out.println();
        printKeyValuesFromPropertiesUsingMatcher(properties);
    }

    private static void printKeyValuesFromPropertiesUsingScanner(String properties) {
        System.out.println("===Using Scanner===");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(properties)) {
            scanner
                    .findAll(pattern)
                    .map(MatchResult::group)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private static void printKeyValuesFromPropertiesUsingMatcher(String properties) {
        System.out.println("===Using Matcher===");
        pattern.matcher(properties).results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Output printed:

```
===Using Scanner===
SectionOne.KeyOne=
SectionOne.KeyTwo=
SectionTwo.UUIDOne=
SectionTwo.UUIDTwo=
SectionTwo.UUIDThree=
SectionTwo.KeyFive=
SectionThree.KeyOne=
SectionThree.KeyTwo=
SectionError.ErrorMessage=
errorlevel=
SectionFour.KeyOne=
SectionLast.KeyOne=

===Using Matcher===
SectionOne.KeyOne=
SectionOne.KeyTwo=
SectionTwo.UUIDOne=
SectionTwo.UUIDTwo=
SectionTwo.UUIDThree=
SectionTwo.KeyFive=
SectionThree.KeyOne=
SectionThree.KeyTwo=
SectionError.ErrorMessage=
SectionFour.KeyOne=
SectionLast.KeyOne=
```

What could be the root cause of this? Do scanner's **findAll** works differently than **matcher**?

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: @Sweeper I have updated the tag. By mistake due to typo it got added. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner`'s documentation mentions the word "buffer" a lot. This suggests that `Scanner` does not know about the entire string from which it is reading, and only holds a small bit of it at a time in a buffer. This makes sense, because `Scanner`s are designed to read from streams as well, reading everything from the stream might take a long time(, or forever!) and takes up a lot of memory.

In the source code of `Scanner`, there is indeed a `CharBuffer`:

```
// Internal buffer used to hold input
private CharBuffer buf;
```

Because of the length and contents of your string, the Scanner has decided to load everything up to...

```
SectionError.ErrorMessage=errorlevel=Warning {HelpMessage:This is very...
                          ^
                    somewhere here
(It could be anywhere in the word "errorlevel")
```

...into the buffer. Then, after that half of the string is read, the other half the string starts like this:

```
errorlevel=Warning {HelpMessage:This is very...
```

`errorLevel=` is now the start of the string, causing the pattern to match.

[Related Bug?](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8176407)

`Matcher` doesn't use a buffer. It stores the whole string against which it is matching in the field:

```
/**
 * The original string being matched.
 */
CharSequence text;
```

So this behaviour is not observed in `Matcher`.

Comment: The bug report is about a delimiter spanning the buffer border. But `findAll` doesn’t use the delimiter.

Comment: @Holger I'm not 100% sure either, which is why I put a "?" there :) I suspect the cause of that bug and this bug are the same. `next` and `findAll` both involve finding a pattern, and that pattern spans across the buffer border.

Comment: Yes, it seems they the are related. When there is a general pattern of failing these scenarios, it raises the question whether all operations are affected. It also overlaps with a performance issue, the `Scanner(String)` constructor should not use a `StringReader` when it could easily use `CharBuffer.wrap(…)` to construct a state as-if having read the entire string already, without the need to copy any data. Of course, the bug would still exist for all other constructors…

Comment: I added an answer to augment this one, providing some test code with a simpler pattern, to demonstrate the issue and also, how this can worked around.

Answer (score 2):

[Sweepers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62341495/2711488) got it right, this is an issue of the `Scanner`’s buffer not containing the entire string. We can simplify the example to trigger the issue specifically:

```
static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^ABC.", Pattern.MULTILINE);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "\nABC1\nXYZ ABC2\nABC3ABC4\nABC4";
    String properties = "X".repeat(1024 - testString.indexOf("ABC4")) + testString;

    String s1 = usingScanner(properties);
    System.out.println("Using Scanner: "+s1);
    String m = usingMatcher(properties);
    System.out.println("Using Matcher: "+m);

    if(!s1.equals(m)) System.out.println("mismatch");
    if(s1.equals(usingScannerNoStream(properties)))
        System.out.println("Not a stream issue");
}
private static String usingScanner(String source) {
    return new Scanner(source)
        .findAll(pattern)
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));
}
private static String usingScannerNoStream(String source) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(source);
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" + ");
    for(;;) {
        String match = s.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);
        if(match == null) return sj.toString();
        sj.add(match);
    }
}
private static String usingMatcher(String source) {
    return pattern.matcher(source).results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));
}
```

which prints:

```
Using Scanner: ABC1 + ABC3 + ABC4 + ABC4
Using Matcher: ABC1 + ABC3 + ABC4
mismatch
Not a stream issue
```

This example prepends a prefix with as much `X` characters needed to align the beginning of the false-positive match with the buffer’s size. The `Scanner`’s initial buffer size is `1024`, though it may get enlarged when needed.

Since `findAll` ignores the scanner’s delimiters, just like `findWithinHorizon`, this code also shows that looping with `findWithinHorizon` manually exhibits the same behavior, in other words, this is not an issue of the Stream API used.

Since `Scanner` will enlarge the buffer when needed, we can work-around the issue by using a match operation that forces the reading of the entire contents into the buffer before performing the intended match operation, e.g.

```
private static String usingScanner(String source) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(source);
    s.useDelimiter("(?s).*").hasNext();
    return s
        .findAll(pattern)
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + "));
}
```

This specific `hasNext()` with a delimiter that consumes the entire string will force the complete buffering of the string, without advancing the position. The subsequent `findAll()` operation ignores both, the delimiter and the result of the `hasNext()` check, but does not suffer from the issue anymore due to the completely filled buffer.

Of course, this destroys the advantage of `Scanner` when parsing an actual stream.